# wtforms, generate fields in constructor

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, jinja2

I need to generate my fields in the constructor of the form since the number of fields needed can vary.  I think my current solution is the problem.  I get an exception when I try to expand the form in my template saying

AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute '**call**'

What is wrong with this code?

```
class DriverTemplateSchedueForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, per_day=30, **kwargs):
        self.per_day = per_day
        ages = model.Agency.query.all()
        ages = [(a.id, a.name) for a in ages]
        self.days = [[[]] * per_day] * 7
        for d in range(7):
            for i in range(per_day):
                lbl = 'item_' + str(d) + '_' + str(i)
                self.__dict__[lbl] = SelectField(lbl, choices=ages)
                self.days[d][i] = self.__dict__[lbl]
        for day in self.days:
            print(day)

        Form.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The fix

You need to add the fields to your *class* not your *instance*:

```
def driver_template_schedue_form(ages, per_day=30, **kwargs):
    """Dynamically creates a driver's schedule form"""

    # First we create the base form
    # Note that we are not adding any fields to it yet
    class DriverTemplateScheduleForm(Form):
        pass

    # Then we iterate over our ranges
    # and create a select field for each
    # item_{d}_{i} in the set, setting each field
    # *on our **class**.
    for d in range(7):
        for i in range(per_day):
            label = 'item_{:d}_{:d}'.format(d, i)
            field = SelectField(label, choices=ages)
            setattr(DriverTemplateScheduleForm, label, field)

    # Finally, we return the *instance* of the class
    # We could also use a dictionary comprehension and then use
    # `type` instead, if that seemed clearer.  That is:
    # type('DriverTemplateScheduleForm', Form, our_fields)(**kwargs)
    return DriverTemplateScheduleForm(**kwargs)
```

#### Why doesn't adding fields to `self` work?

WTForms uses meta-classes to register forms and fields together and preserve order. `*Field` instances are created unbound, [added to the `Form` class' `_unbound_fields` attribute](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/3f955152b64a75b1d8cebf35bc9761a7216f4abd/wtforms/form.py#L193-L203) and are bound to the class instance [when the class is being constructed by the meta-class](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/3f955152b64a75b1d8cebf35bc9761a7216f4abd/wtforms/form.py#L52).

By the time `DriverTemplateScheduleForm.__init__` is run, `_unbound_fields` has already been populated.  You *can* push your fields into `self._unbound_fields` and things would also *just work*, but that's making use of a private API and so may break later.

Answer (score 2):

The answer about meta-class is right, but in case if you really need this (like I do):

```
class SomeForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for name in kwargs.keys():
            if name.startswith('PREFIX_'):
                field = HiddenField()
                setattr(self, name, field)
                self._unbound_fields = self._unbound_fields + [[name, field]]
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that we're not modifying `_unbound_fields`, not to have this fields in form class next time.